# Advanced cursor for data selection in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, string-aggregation

below mentioned code for cursor works only in Oracle 11g, as LISTAGG() function introduced starting version 11g. I need to adapt this code for Oracle 10g. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t3.field1), t3.field2,
       LISTAGG(t3.field3, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t3.field3),
       SUM(t2.field1), SUM(t2.field2), SUM(t3.field3)
  FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
 WHERE t1.id = t2.idoft1
   AND t2.id = t3.idoft2
GROUP BY t3.field1, t3.field2;
```

Comment: Oracle-Base has [lots of different options for you](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Tom Kyte's STRAGG function](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11591.html)